# Can't return a string after value is true in coroutine

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, return, coroutine

I'm having an issue with this coroutine I need to run. It keeps spitting out an error saying that it can't convert WaitUntil to string, and when I add WaitUntil to the return types, it spits another saying it can't be returned. I've tried researching for a few hours now to no avail. Here's the snippit of code:

```
     public string OpenSaveDialog(string Title, string OpenLocation, string[] AllowedExtentions)
     {
         OpenBtn.GetComponentInChildren<TMPro.TMP_Text>().text = "Save";
         TitleText.text = Title;
         AllowFileNameTyping = true;
         MultiSelect = false;

         LoadIntoExplorer(PathInput, AllowedExtentions);

         return StartCoroutine(WaitForFinish()); // Error here: Cannot implicitly convert type 'UnityEngine.Coroutine' to 'string'
     }

     IEnumerator<string> WaitForFinish()
     {
         yield return new WaitUntil(() => Done == true); // Error here: Cannot implicitly convert type 'UnityEngine.WaitUntil' to 'string'
         yield return FilePathsSelected[0];
     }
```

Comment: Because I need it to return a string in the end, I have a feeling that's not how it works though... And in that case, how would I get it to return a string without changing everything into a coroutine?

Comment: Yep alright, but is there a way to return a value from a coroutine that _isn't_ Coroutine, so I can then return it in my function?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot return a value from a Coroutine, your options are making a callback, class scope variable, that indicates the value of the coroutine, custom class, that has an IsDone & value or result property, you also cannot use ref, in or out keywords too because iterators cannot use them :/ so this would not work:

```
public IEnumerator WaitForFinnish(ref string value)
{
    yield return new WaitUntil(() => true);
    value = "value";
}
```

So in your case i would do something like this:

```
string filePath = string.Empty;

public void OpenSaveDialog(string Title, string OpenLocation, string[] AllowedExtentions)
{
     OpenBtn.GetComponentInChildren<TMPro.TMP_Text>().text = "Save";
     TitleText.text = Title;
     AllowFileNameTyping = true;
     MultiSelect = false;

     LoadIntoExplorer(PathInput, AllowedExtentions);

     StartCoroutine(WaitForFinish());
 }

 IEnumerator WaitForFinish()
 {
     yield return new WaitUntil(() => Done); // Also don't do bool == true or false,
                                             // it will trigger most of the programmers :D
     filePath = FilePathsSelected[0];
 }
```

Answer (score 4):

Adding to [Menyus' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59422427/7111561)

I would rather go for a callback method

```
public void OpenSaveDialog(string Title, string OpenLocation, string[] AllowedExtentions, Action<string> whenDone = null)
 {
     OpenBtn.GetComponentInChildren<TMPro.TMP_Text>().text = "Save";
     TitleText.text = Title;
     AllowFileNameTyping = true;
     MultiSelect = false;

     LoadIntoExplorer(PathInput, AllowedExtentions);

     StartCoroutine(WaitForFinish(whenDone));
 }

 IEnumerator WaitForFinish(Action<string> whenDone)
 {
     yield return new WaitUntil(() => Done);

     whenDone?.Invoke(FilePathsSelected[0]);
 }
```

So now whenever calling the method you can pass in an action that should be executed when done like e.g.

```
// as lambda expression
OpenSaveDialog("Title", "Some/Path", new []{ ".example" }, path =>
    {
        Debug.Log($"The selected path is {path}");
    });

//Or with a dedicated method 
OpenSaveDialog("Title", "Some/Path", new []{ ".example" }, OnPathSelected);

...

private void OnPathSelected (string path)
{
    Debug.Log($"The selected path is {path}");
}
```

---

Ofcourse we can't see what `LoadIntoExplorer` does exactly. Probably you could even skip the coroutine entirely and rather add an `Action<string>` callback to that method instead?